# Zsh: how to auto complete after a command?

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, zsh, autocomplete

everyone. It's a little difficult to explain what I want to do.

I want to create a script 'example', which can input long commands for you after you run it with short parameters. For example,

```
$ example server # I input this line manually
$ ssh user@192.168.1.2 # This line is automatically generated by the above command
```

So that I can edit the command line at the current line.

I am using shell `ZSH`. And I've tried something like `history` but failed at the end. 
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not possible (or at least very hackish) to run an external script, so that anything is placed on the prompt for further editing

That being said, it is possible to extend zle (zsh's command line editor) with your own functions, so-called widgets.

Any user-defined widget has access to `BUFFER`, which contains the edit buffer and may also be modified.

Here a short prototype:

```
function example () {
    if [[ $BUFFER = 'server' ]]; then
        LBUFFER='ssh user@192.168.1.2 '
    else
        zle accept-line
    fi
}

zle -N example
bindkey '^M' example
```

`zle -N example` creates a new widget named `example` and maps it to the function with the same name. `bindkey '^M' example` maps <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, also known as <kbd>Return</kbd>, to the widget `example`. So everytime you just type "server" and press <kbd>Return</kbd> it gets replaced by `ssh user@192.168.1.2` and the cursor is placed at the end for further editing, while any other line is executed/accepted as-is.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a shell function, you can also use a keybinding. For example like that:

```
bindkey -s '\C-e\C-l' 'ssh user@192.168.1.2'
```

Here `-s` creates a string substitution, see `man zshzle`:

> `-s in-string out-string ...`                  Bind each in-string to each out-string.  When in-string is typed, out-string will be pushed back  and  treated  as
>                        input to the line editor.  When -R is also used, interpret the in-strings as ranges.

With the above example  you can use <kbd>CTRL+E</kbd>,<kbd>CTRL+L</kbd> in insert `ssh user@192.168.1.2` into the command line at the current cursor position.

This has the advantage, that you can use this shortcut easily to construt a pipe, e.g.

```
cat foo | CTRL+E,CTRL+L  =>  cat foo | ssh user@192.168.1.2
```